# Where is '/?' parameter expansion documented?

Tags: bash, dash, bash-expansion

I came across this weird parameter expansion for bash/dash which I don't find any reference for. What is this sort of expansion called? Where is it documented?

```
$ /???
bash: /bin: Is a directory
$ /????
bash: /boot: Is a directory
$ /?????
bash: /cdrom: Is a directory
$ /??????
bash: /libx32: Is a directory
```

Comment: The `?` behaves as `.` does in regular expressions; it matches one character. This is documented in your shell's manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [pathname expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06) using shell [pattern matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13): `?` matches any single character, so `/???` expands to every three-character filename in `/` in alphabetical order.

That makes `/bin` first on most systems, which is a directory and not an executable, so you get the error you posted.

This is the same sort of expansion as `*`, and might be useful for cases like `cp file??.txt dest` where a set of files have a common structure to their names with only a few fixed characters changing.